# Is that possible to take numerical integration of a function that depends on other variables in addition to the integration variable?

Tags: numerical-integration

As I know, the result of a numerical integration should be a number. However, there are situations at which we have a multivariate function but we want to integrate only over one variable and use the result at the next steps of our problem. On the other hand, the function is complicated and we cannot obtain an analytical expression. So, is that possible to do numerical integration over one variable while the function depends on other variables as well? As example, consider the following integral. The integration is over $v$, but the function depends on $\delta_2$ and $\delta_3$, too.

```
c = 3 10^8;
L = 0.07;
ϵ0 = 8.85 10^-12;
hbar = 10^-34;
μ13 = 2.06 10^-29;
μ23 = 2.06 10^-29;
μ24 = 2 10^-29;
μ14 = 2 10^-29;
OD = 46.6;
Γ41 = 18840000;
Γ31 = 0.5 18840000;
Γ11 = 0.02 Γ41;
Γ21 = 0.04 Γ41;
Γ22 = 0.02 Γ41;
Γ24 = Γ41;
Δ1 = 130 Γ41;
Δ3 = -3 Γ41;
Δ2 = 3 Γ41;
Ω2 = 15 Γ41;
Ω3 = 15 Γ41;
λ13 = 795 10^-9;
λ23 = 795 10^-9;
λ14 = 780 10^-9;
λ24 = 780 10^-9;
ω24 = 2 π/λ24;
ω14 = 2 π/λ14;
ω13 = 2 π/λ13;
ω23 = 2 π/λ23;
ΔD1 = Δ1 + v/λ13;
ΔD2 = Δ2 - v/λ24;
ΔD3 = Δ3 + v/λ24;
ω1 = ω13 - Δ1;
ω2 = ω24 - Δ2;
ω3 = ω24 - Δ3;
ωs1 = ω23 - Δ1;
ωs2 = ω24 - Δ2;
ωs3 = ω14 - Δ3;
k1 = ω1/c;
k2 = ω2/c;
k3 = ω3/c;
mRb = 85.467*1.6606*10^-27;
kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
T = 353.15;
NN = 1.2*10^11;
WDp = (1 + v/c);
WDn = (1 - v/c);

f[v_] := Sqrt[mRb/(2 π kB T)] Exp[-((mRb v^2)/(2 kB T))];

(* the denominator of the integrand *)
Den[δ2_, δ3_] := ϵ0 hbar^5 ((Γ31 + I ΔD1)) ((Γ21 + I WDn δ2 + 
    I WDp δ3) (Γ41 + I WDn δ2 + 
    I WDp δ3 + I ΔD2) + Ω2*
  Conjugate[Ω2]) ((Γ11 + 
    I WDp δ3) (Γ41 + I WDp δ3 + 
    I ΔD3) + Ω3* Conjugate[Ω3]);

(* The integration over v, which should give a function of δ2 and δ3. This part 
should be done numerically *)

result = Integrate[f[v] (2 NN μ13 μ24 μ23 μ14^3)/Den[δ2, δ3], {v, -800, 800}];
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, **no**. Numerical integration works on numbers, not symbols.